# How to change entity state inside SaveChanges method in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, savechanges

> I want to change the behavior of delete method in EF Core.
> Basically
> I do not want to delete any entity, I just want to change Deleted flag
> to true.

I have this method:

```
 public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<BaseEntity>())
        {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.Entity.InsertBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                    entry.Entity.InsertDate = DateTime.Now;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.Entity.UpdateBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                    entry.Entity.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Deleted:
                   // entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                    entry.Entity.Deleted = true;
                    entry.Entity.DeletedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
                    entry.Entity.DeletedDate = DateTime.Now;
                   // ChangeTracker.AcceptAllChanges();
                    break;
            }
        }

        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
```

I tried to change STATE from Deleted to Modified, update the entity and let the method run until the end, expecting to do an update instead of Delete, but is not working as I expected.

I also observe that if I do the changed to the entity than call "SaveChanges()" the entity is saved but then that instance of DbContext cannot be used to query the same table, the error received is:

> "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute."

I don't know much about how "DbContext - SaveChanges" works, and I hope you can give me a solution to this issue.

Comment: Are you able to add a field named 'Deleted' or isDeleted and set that instead?

Comment: I have a field Deleted on all entities, but I want to set it to true inside SaveChanges method